# Why String element orders in VS IDE debug mode is different with memory order in C#?

Tags: c#, string, memory, unicode, character-encoding

Can anyone say why string character orders is variant with immediate window ?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDv0y.jpg

[image]

Comment: Displaying text with Arabic, Hebrew or Farsi glyphs on a window that is not configured to render RTL is unpredictable.  Ultimately there are two very different text rendering engines at work here, the editor text is displayed by WPF code, the Immediate Window is a wrapper for native code.  The legacy text render engine takes a stab at it without needing a cue from U+200F, tends to not turn out so well if the text also contains Western glyphs or punctuation.

Comment: @HansPassant : is there any way to get what displayed by wpf code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the picture you are talking about showing string with RTL text in it. Correct visual representation of such text (especially with LTR characters like "?" mixed in) is different from in memory order.

The only reliable way I know to see characters in order they are stored is to convert to char or int array and look or print that array. All other ways may try to render string following at least some of RTL rules.